# Datagrid show a blank column not required at the end in ASP NET C#

Tags: c#, gridview, nested

I am using `nested datagrids` from this [tutorial](https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/gridview-with-in-gridview-or-nested.html)

The expand/collapse options working correctly, but at the end `datagrid` a blank column appears that I can't understand what it means... and nor to hide using `rowdatabound` in `datagrid`...

This is the **HTML code**

```
<tr align="center">
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">FIRST</th>
    <th class="hidden" scope="col" style="width:0px;">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
```

Any help would greatly appreciate... my code below... Thank you...

**.javascript**

```
function divexpandcollapse(divname) {
    var div = document.getElementById(divname);
    var img = document.getElementById('img' + divname);
    if (div.style.display == "none") {
        div.style.display = "inline";
        img.src = "/aspnet/img/minus.png";
    } else {
        div.style.display = "none";
        img.src = "/aspnet/img/plus.png";
    }
}
```

**.aspx markup**

```
<%--START GRIDVIEW --%>
<asp:GridView ID="gvProducts"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server"
    DataKeyNames="sID">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrows" />
    <Columns>
       
       <%--EXPANDED ROW NESTED GRIDVIEW --%>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10" ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("sID") %>');">
                    <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("sID") %>"
                        src="/aspnet/img/plus.png" alt="" /></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new"
           ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
           DataField="FIRST"
           HeaderText="FIRST"
           ReadOnly="true"
           HtmlEncode="false" />                    

       <%--START NESTED GRIDVIEW --%>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="100">
                        <div id="div<%# Eval("sID") %>"
                            style="overflow: auto; display: none; position: relative; left: 3px; overflow: auto">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gv_Child" runat="server"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                DataKeyNames="sID"
                                CssClass="mGrid" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new"
                                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                        DataField="SECOND"
                                        HeaderText="SECOND"
                                        ReadOnly="true"
                                        HtmlEncode="false" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%--END NESTED GRIDVIEW --%>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView><%--END GRIDVIEW --%>
```

**Return datagrid in browser Chrome**

[image]

**CSS Style**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <style>
        th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

//Gridview

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
    th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Use this CSS code to hide the column(s).

Comment: thanks for suggestion... how to use the style sheet if in my aspx code i don't have the column?

Comment: the <style> block above can be used anywhere in the <body>. If you want do not want to write css code in the page then use external CSS and write the above css in the external stylesheet file and use in your code.

Comment: thanks I have tried your suggestion without success. Please see **Return datagrid in browser Chrome**on the question, I have posted the return of datagrid in browser Google Chrome... after the column with date/hour the column not required...

Comment: can you share where did you apply the style code?